# PDO error handling not being fired

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been using the standard PHP error reporting, but decided to attempt a try catch with PDO. I'm going to turn off error reporting with `error_reporting(0)`and use custom error handling.

My `try-catch` or `!isnull(error)` doesn't fire. Can some suggest how to achieve the error handling without the default reporting?

What am i doing wrong?

**PHP**

```
    $db = connect();
    try
    {
        foreach ($data['ids'] as $item_id)
        {
            $sql = 
            "UPDATE item 
             SET verified = !verified 
             WHERE item_id = :room_id";  //this line is incorrect and should cause error

            $update = $db -> prepare($sql);
            $update -> bindParam(":item_id", $item_id);
            $update -> execute();
            $error = $db -> errorInfo();
            $update -> closeCursor();
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "ERROR : Server Error -". $e -> getMessage();

    }

    if (!is_null($error[2])) 
    {
        echo "Query failed! ". $error[2];
    }
```

Comment: Have you set the error mode to exception? Basically `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: You're doing everything upside down. try-catch has nothing to do with proper handling, not to mention error_reporting(0). [Read this](http://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors). Also note that your prepared statement is wrong as well. You have to prepare and bind only once.

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois- Thanks this is it....Although is there a way to get the detailed infomation (page name and line number) like the reporting warnings output?

Comment: @Your Common Sense- Thanks for the info (good guide). I saw the "Prepared statements. Multiple execution" section, seems passing data into execute replaces the binds...thanks again.